# Is there an R equivalent to Excel's LOGEST function?

Tags: r

I need to exactly replicate Excel's [LOGEST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/logest-function-f27462d8-3657-4030-866b-a272c1d18b4b) function in R, but can't find a way of doing it without using generic least squares estimation. Before I write some custom code myself, has anyone come across such a thing?

```
data <- 2:7
```

Desired output (from Excel's LOGEST function):

```
1.27730742  1.758076359
```

Comment: Are those the `y`'s or the `x`'s?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569068/fitting-logarithmic-curve-in-r) may be relevant to your question

Comment: Those are the `y`s. Excel will infer the `x`s if they're not given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just log the data, do a linear regression, then exp the results.

```
result <- lm(log(data) ~ seq_along(data))
exp(result$coefficients)
```

(I would have found this earlier but I was getting loge and log10 confused like a fool.)

EDIT: [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas) has kindly made this into a function: here it is:

```
logest <- function(y, x, ...){
  if(missing(x) || is.null(x)) x <- seq_along(y)
  result <- lm(log(y) ~ x, ...)
  exp(coef(result))
}

data <- 2:7
logest(data)
#(Intercept)           x 
#   1.758076    1.277307
```

Comment: See my answer. I believe you should include its code in your answer. It does nothing more than to rewrite your code as a function.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is entirely based in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62435360/8245406) by user [@MattB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13566593/mattb).

```
logest <- function(y, x, ...){
  if(missing(x) || is.null(x)) x <- seq_along(y)
  result <- lm(log(y) ~ x, ...)
  exp(coef(result))
}

data <- 2:7
logest(data)
#(Intercept)           x 
#   1.758076    1.277307
```

This second example uses the example data in the question link. The results are equal to the results posted there.

```
x <- 11:16
y <- c(33100, 47300, 69000, 102000, 150000, 220000)
logest(y, x)
#(Intercept)           x 
# 495.304770    1.463276
```